# Playbook failed condition

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that checks the disk usage available in my cluster :

```
.....
#Test
    - set_fact: diskFree=0
    - set_fact:
        diskFree="{{(100.0 * (item.size_available / item.size_total)) | round(2, 'common')}}"
      when:
        - skipDevice not in item.device
        - sizeThreshold is undefined or (sizeThreshold is defined and ((100.0 * (item.size_available / item.size_total)) | round(2, 'common')) < sizeThreshold|float)
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
    #Test Display
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}: {{ diskFree }}"
      when: diskFree != 0
```

The thing is, I want the playbook to fail when the disk usage is under 20%, but I coudn't found out how to do it and I can't use `failed_when` in here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the current output of the playbook.

Comment: `TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: test_disk.yml:53
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "host1: 73.47"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "host2: 67.37"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "host3: 59.18"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, add a `fail` task:

```
- fail:
    msg: "Free disk space below 20% ({{ diskFree }}%)."
  when: diskFree|float < 20.0
```

Comment: I did it already, but I got this error :

`The conditional check 'diskFree < 20' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if diskFree < 20 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): '<' not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText'`

Comment: Right.  Need to cast it with `|float`.  Fixed in answer.

Comment: Works like a sharm now, thanks for the 'float' tip.